# Including a link to an SVG file within Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am inserting a button within the page using JQuery.  Within the button is an SVG.  I would like to instead of having SVG in the .js file, have a link to a seperate svg file.  I have included part of the file below.  As you can see, it is very unreadable, so I would much prefer to hold it elsewhere..

```
var feedButton = '<button title="Share to feed" data-original-title="Feed" data-container="body" data-delay="50" data-position="top" class="tooltipped send-to-feed" type="button"><svg class="feed-button-icon" viewBox="0 0 38 37"><g fill="none"><path d="M0 0L24 0 24 24 0 24 0 0Z"/><path d="M17 17C17 17 17 17 17 17L8 17C8 17 8 17 8 17L8 14 6 14 6 19C 6 20.1 6.9 21 8 21L17 21C18.1 21 19 20.1 19 19L19 5 17 5 17 17ZM17 3C18.1 3 19 3.9 19 5L17 5 17 3ZM6 5C6 3.9 6.9 3 8 3L8 5 6 5ZM3 10L3 12 11 12 11 14 14 11 11 8 11 10 3 10ZM6 5L8 5 8 8 6 8 6 5ZM8 3L17 3 17 5 8 5 8 3Z" fill="white"/></g></svg></button>';

shotitem.find('.feed-button').html(feedButton);
```

Comment: Why don't you save the svg as a file and simple use `<img src="mySVG.svg" />` to display it? I think inserting it as an image will reduce your code significantly.

Comment: You can always make an AJAX request to get the contents of an SVG image file on your server, and then take the response and put it into your button ...

Comment: @somethinghere: Embedding SVG as external resources rather limits your abilities to format it differently at different times via CSS; therefor embedding it as `<svg>` can be preferable. https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-6

Comment: @CBroe I am aware of that, but in this case it seemed to simplify the code greatly. Loading it with AJAX is a good solution, but will increase code complexity.

Comment: Thanks guys - prefer to keep as an <svg> for the CSS reason mentioned above - Ajax probably a bit overkill for this one, good to be aware of for the future though!